# What are those monsters on Relia's backpack called?

Tags: star-ocean-5

I noticed those cute monsters on Relia's backpack:

> [image: cute monsters on Relia's backpack]

What are those called? Are they mentioned somewhere else in *Star Ocean* game itself?

Comment: I think this question should stay open because it includes a screenshot or picture of the identification request in question, which is allowed.

Comment: @Pyritie turns out it's not game identification after all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are called **Onigumo**, which seems to be a popular mascot character in the Kingdom of Resulia.

> リュックには“オニグモ”というレスリア王国で人気のマスコットが描かれている。
> There's "Onigumo" on the back of the backpack, a popular mascot in the Kingdom of Resulia.
>
> <sup>[*Famitsu.com* (Japanese)](https://www.famitsu.com/news/201603/29102233.html)</sup>

There's also Onigumo strap on Miki's staff.

[image: Onigumo strap on Miki's wand]

And an in-game item as a pre-order bonus

[image: Onigumo strap]

<sup>Onigumo strap accessory as a pre-order bonus from GEO Hyper Media Shop</sup>

However, it's an original character for *Star Ocean 5*, it's not based on any games.

As for whether it's mentioned somewhere else or not, unfortunately I can't answer that since I don't play the game.